# mongodb date mongolian deadbeef

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js

I'm using the [mongolian deadbeef client](https://github.com/marcello3d/node-mongolian) for [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

I have a document like this:

```
{
  "time": 1308651397345,
  "_id": {
      "$oid": "4e006f853d93e4676e00000a"
  }
}
```

But when I access it with the [mongolian deadbeef client](https://github.com/marcello3d/node-mongolian), I see:

```
{ 
  time: { low_: -1313627935, high_: 304 },
  _id: 4e006f853d93e4676e00000a 
}
```

How do I access the correct time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `time.toNumber()`, what you see is a 64 bit long being split into two 32 bits ints.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that [Mongo ObjectIds](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) contain the timestamp within them. It would save space just to use the _id.

I've never used node.js or mongolian beef. However, this works from the mongo client

```
> var foo = new ObjectId()                                            
> foo.getTimestamp()                                                  
ISODate("2012-08-06T12:58:15Z")                                       
> foo.getTimestamp                                                    
function () {                                                         
    return new Date(parseInt(this.toString().slice(0, 8), 16) * 1000);
}
```

The last part shows you how you can implement getTimeStamp() yourself.

Finally be aware that [10gen](http://www.10gen.com) has released an [officially supported node.js driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native).

Comment: How do I get the time from the Mongo ObjectId? Also, what if the time being stored is not the same time that the db record was created?